# How can I prevent link_to from escaping slashes in URL parameters in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Having this route:

```
map.foo 'foo/*path', :controller => 'foo', :action => 'index'
```

I have the following results for the `link_to` call

```
link_to "Foo", :controller => 'foo', :path => 'bar/baz'
# <a href="/foo/bar%2Fbaz">Foo</a>
```

Calling `url_for` or `foo_url` directly, even with `:escape => false`, give me the same url:

```
foo_url(:path => 'bar/baz', :escape => false, :only_path => true)
# /foo/bar%2Fbaz
```

I want the resulting url to be: `/foo/bar/baz`

Is there a way around this without patching rails?

Comment: oops turns out rubyonrails is not the best tag for that, apologies.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead of passing path a string, give it an array.

```
link_to "Foo", :controller => 'foo', :path => %w(bar baz)
# <a href="/foo/bar/baz">Foo</a>
```

If you didn't have the route in your routes file, this same link_to would instead create this:

```
# <a href="/foo?path[]=bar&path[]=baz">Foo</a>
```

The only place I could find this documented is in [this ticket](http://dev.rubyonrails.org/ticket/7047).

Answer (score -3):

Any reason why you're needing to generate the URL with that path though?

It would be cleaner to just define an extra route to cover that URL.

Comment: Please use the comment feature for clarifications and such ;-)